# Jmeter - craft json to post a request

Tags: java, jmeter

I have to send 150 requests simultaneously for some duration say 1 to 2 hours or a day to perform a load test on an application.
the request has to be crafted before it's been posted as you could see in the below JSON. the timestamp has to consecutive time with a difference of 1 second. The deviceID has to be rotated I have a thousand devices so after 1000 devices those have to be circulated. There are 3 tripinfodatamodel events. In my actual request, this might vary between 60 to 120. The epoch timestamp in the eventDateTime and IgnitionONTime are the one which is a second apart in consecutive events. Any suggestions on how can I craft this request?

```
 "events":[
      {
         "deviceDetailsDataModel":{
            "deviceId":"<deviceID>"
         },
         "eventDateTime":1601481829000,
         "tripInfoDataModel":{
            "ignitionStatus":"ON",
            "ignitionONTime":1601481829000
         }
      },
      {
         "deviceDetailsDataModel":{
            "deviceId":"<deviceID>"
         },
         "eventDateTime":1601481830000,
         "tripInfoDataModel":{
            "ignitionStatus":"ON",
            "ignitionONTime":1601481830000
         }
      },
      {
         "deviceDetailsDataModel":{
            "deviceId":"<deviceID>"
         },
         "eventDateTime":1601481831000,
         "tripInfoDataModel":{
            "ignitionOFFTime":1601481831000,
            "ignitionStatus":"OFF"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For rotating 1000 device IDs put them into a .csv file and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for reading the values in the runtime
2. For obtaining current timestamp and adding 1 and 2 seconds to it you can use [__timeShift() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function) like:

   ```
   {
     "events": [
       {
         "deviceDetailsDataModel": {
           "deviceId": "${deviceID}"
         },
         "eventDateTime": ${__timeShift(,,,,now)},
         "tripInfoDataModel": {
           "ignitionStatus": "ON",
           "ignitionONTime": ${now}
         }
       },
       {
         "deviceDetailsDataModel": {
           "deviceId": "${deviceID}"
         },
         "eventDateTime": ${__timeShift(,${now},PT1S,,plus1second)},
         "tripInfoDataModel": {
           "ignitionStatus": "ON",
           "ignitionONTime": ${plus1second}
         }
       },
       {
         "deviceDetailsDataModel": {
           "deviceId": "${deviceID}"
         },
         "eventDateTime": ${__timeShift(,${now},PT2S,,plus2seconds)},
         "tripInfoDataModel": {
           "ignitionOFFTime": ${plus2seconds},
           "ignitionStatus": "OFF"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```